# Show All per page

Tags: error, catalogsearch

I am having a problem with the show all Per page under search. It shows only one product. Show 9, 15, 30, 60 works just fine. Also in the product page is working fine. The problem is only on Search.

example: https://www.shoebox.com.cy/index.php/catalogsearch/result/?q=carrera

Any ideas?

Comment: please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185422/magento-quick-search-returns-all-products

Comment: Eh, that's an ajaxified product list view. Switch to default theme and test to determine whether the issue is with the collection being returned (doubtful) or an issue with displaying the listing returned (more likely). Then update your question with the results.

Comment: Same with the default theme.